# Setup a <select> dropdown list dynamically from a SQL Server database table

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, html-select

I'm trying to setup a dropdown list to pull from a table in a SQL Server database. I am using aspx with code behind to submit data to the SQL Server database. Ultimately, what I need to have happen is to display customer names in a drop down list then submit that data to another database table. Using `<asp:DropDownList>` is an option but I am submitting the data by the name attribute and I cannot set a specific name to the asp webform object. I have not used php in my form as of yet and would like to stay clear if at all possible.

aspx html code:

```
<select id="customerName" name="custName" class="txtbxList">
 <option></option>
 <option></option>
 <option></option>
</select>
```

asp DropDownSOurce and List Tags

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:csusaCentralConnection %>' SelectCommand="SELECT [customerNameDD] FROM [customerNameList]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
<asp:DropDownList ID="customerName" CssClass="txtbxList" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="customerNameDD" DataValueField="customerNameDD"></asp:DropDownList>
```

My code-behind:

```
string coName = Request.Form["custName"];
string generalInfo = @"INSERT INTO generalInfo(CustomerName)VALUES(@custName);

        SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["csusaCentralConnection"].ConnectionString);

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(generalInfo, conn);

        //NAME of input field in aspx file

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("custName", coName);

        conn.Open();
        string rowIdentity = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        conn.Close();
```

Comment: I don't understand _"Using DropDownList is an option but I am submitting the data by the name attribute and I cannot set a specific name to the asp webform object"_

Comment: what part of this don't you understand?   I am kind of new to c# and submitting to sql but from my understanding you can only use the name attribute to submit data to a sql database?

Comment: Your understanding is incorrect.  It's more normal for dropdown lists to display the name, but submit the id.

Comment: Is that also for basic html <input> tags as well?   I have a buddy showing me the ropes whenever I get stuck and he states that submitting to an sql database table, you should use the name attribute rather than then ID attribute.    btw, Dan, thanks info.

Comment: Is this the same question you asked yesterday in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17437295/using-the-select-html-tag-to-pull-data-from-sql-database-table ? The articles linked in the comments should solve your problem.

Comment: Whether your friend's advice is good or bad depends on the context.  For the insert query you showed, passing the name is correct because it matches up with the corresponding field in that table.  However, storing the customer name instead of the id in your generalInfo table might not be such a great idea.  If you are not familiar with the term "normalized database", I've heard good things about the book, Database Design for Mere Mortals.

Comment: Jeremy, the posting from yesterday was said to be off-topic.  I was asked to place detailed information in my question.   The links helped, and I understand I can use the asp:DropDownList to accomplish what i was looking for but I was not aware of using the ID rather than the name attribute.  Jeremy, thank you for being such a massive help!

Comment: @SeanRobbins Just to clarify the list of names is rendering correctly? You are just having trouble with getting the data on post back?

Comment: @BrentMannering Correct, I was until I just used the ID to post back and I get no errors using the asp dropdownlist.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using the designer to setup your dropdown list data source.  Here is how you could do it in code:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!this.IsPostBack)
        {
            MyLinqToSqlDataContext db = new MyLinqToSqlDataContext();
            var result = from c in db.Customers
                         select g;
            customerName.DataSource = result.ToList();
            customerName.DataTextField = "Name";
            customerName.DataValueField = "ID";
            customerName.DataBind();
            ...
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of it you're most of the way there, you should only need to change this line:

```
string coName = Request.Form["custName"];
```

To:

```
string coName = customerName.SelectedValue;
```